# How to get entities as an array in a class component when using createEntityAdapter from Redux toolkit?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, mapstatetoprops

I have a slice in my store I created with **createEntityAdapter** from [Redux Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createEntityAdapter#selector-functions). In Function components you can use **useSelector** with the selectors returned from `adapter.getSelectors()`.
But how can I get all entities as an array (like with the selectAll selector) in a class based component? I am using **connect** with **mapStateToProps**, which just allows me to get either entities or ids as a prop, but not all entities as an array sorted in the same order as the ids are sorted...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would use the same `selectAll` selector, but you would call it in your `mapState` function for use with `connect` instead of passing it to `useSelector`:

```js
const mapState = (state) => {
  return {
    items: itemsSelectors.selectAll(state)
  }
}
```